# Can I get my site to ignore google translate toolbr

Tags: google-chrome, multilingual, google-translate

I am developing a multilingual site and want to try and get chrome to ignore the automatic google translation option. I have pages which will be professionally translated and a language switcher.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Use 
`<meta name="google" content="notranslate" />` 
in head.

Source: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en